# How to serialize JSON with nested dictionaries having dynamic keys in C#?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I am working on a C# project where I need to deserialize a JSON string that contains nested dictionaries with dynamic keys. The structure of the JSON is quite complex, with multiple levels of nesting, and the keys of the dictionaries at various levels can change dynamically. I am using Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) for JSON processing.

```json
{
  "count": "57",
  "pages": 2,
  "page": 1,
  "list": [
    {
      "product_id": "30",
      "attributes": {
        "5": {
          "16": "YES",
          "15": "30°C",
          "14": "YES"
        },
        "6": {
          "30": "asd",
          "21": "Collar",
          "18": "Solid Color"
        }
      },
      // Other product details...
    },
    {
      "product_id": "31",
      "attributes": {
        "5": {
          "16": [],
          "15": [],
          "14": []
        },
        "6": {
          "30": [],
          "21": [],
          "18": []
        },
      },
      // Other product details...
    },
    {
      "product_id": "32",
      "attributes": {
        "5":[],
        "6":[],
      },
      // Other product details...
    },
    {
      "product_id": "33",
      "attributes": [],
      // Other product details...
    }
    // Other products...
  ]
}
```

I'm using this property for attributes

```cs
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(AttributesConverter))]
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Attributes { get; set; }
```

And i have this Converter for attribures

```cs
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
            var result = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

            if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            {
                foreach (var prop in token.Children<JProperty>())
                {
                    var key = prop.Name;
                    var value = prop.Value;

                    if (value.Type == JTokenType.String)
                    {
                        var newDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                        newDict[key] = value.ToString();
                        result[key] = newDict;
                    }
                    else if (value.Type == JTokenType.Integer)
                    {
                        var newDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                        newDict[key] = value.ToString();
                        result[key] = newDict;
                    }
                    else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array && !token.HasValues)
                    {
                        return new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    }
                    else if (value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
                    {
                        result[key] = value.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // empty array
                        // result[key] = value.ToObject<Dictionary<string, string>>();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array && !token.HasValues)
            {
                return new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

but Im doing somthing wrong and getting this error

```bash
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.Object]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[System.String,System.String]]'.
```

if i use `Dictionary<string,dynamic>` and bit different logic in `ReadJson()` it will parse it correctly, but dont want to use dynamic because i need to Serialize/Deserialize it to xml.

Could anyone provide guidance or example code how to handle it?
Thank you in advance for your help :)

edit:
I edit my converter because i paste wrong one.

Comment: At which line ?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.SetValue(Object target, Object value) in DynamicValueProvider.cs:line 92
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target) in JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 1058

Comment: Why are you processing at token level? Try to iterate through JObject properties
foreach(var prop in JObject.Load(reader).Properties())
...
Then you can convert the value to string through prop.Value.ToString()
To check if the property is a object you can compare prop.Value against JObject

Comment: In addiction, your sample json seems to have some inconsistence. In the last attribute item (product_id="33"), you have an attributes property with a empty array as value whereas for all other products it is an object ({ }). I think if you have no attributes for a product the value in json should be null.

Comment: That's one of the reasons I have a problem with it. Unfortunately, I have no influence on the structure of this json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering suggests that there's a mismatch between the expected type `(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>)` and the actual type being deserialized `(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>)`. This likely occurs when deserializing nested dictionaries where the inner dictionary is of type `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of `Dictionary<string, string>`.

To fix this issue, you need to ensure that you correctly handle the deserialization of nested dictionaries. Instead of directly deserializing inner dictionaries as `Dictionary<string, string>`, you should handle them as `Dictionary<string, object>` and then recursively convert them if necessary. Here's the modified version of your converter:

```
public class AttributesConverter : JsonConverter
```

{
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
return objectType == typeof(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>);
}

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
    var result = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

    if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        foreach (var prop in token.Children<JProperty>())
        {
            var key = prop.Name;
            var value = prop.Value;

            if (value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            {
                result[key] = ConvertToObjectDictionary(value);
            }
            else if (value.Type == JTokenType.Array && !value.HasValues)
            {
                result[key] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle other value types as needed
                var innerDict = new Dictionary<string, string> { { key, value.ToString() } };
                result[key] = innerDict;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array && !token.HasValues)
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }

    return result;
}

private Dictionary<string, string> ConvertToObjectDictionary(JToken token)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var prop in token.Children<JProperty>())
    {
        var key = prop.Name;
        var value = prop.Value;

        if (value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            result[key] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        }
        else
        {
            result[key] = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

}

This converter ensures that when you encounter nested dictionaries, you handle them appropriately by converting them to `Dictionary<string, string>` recursively if necessary. Make sure to adjust the conversion logic according to your specific requirements.